# Calling a method in another method?

Tags: iphone

I've got a delegate method which just has a bit of code in there that puts a % sign on the end of the number entered.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)UItextfield {
     NSString *oldTextFieldValue = UItextfield.text;
     UItextfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %%",oldTextFieldValue];
   }
```

Could I instead of having that, have the following action

```
-(IBAction)Calculate:(UITextField *)UITextfield;
{
    NSString *oldTextFieldValue = UItextfield.text;
    UItextfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %%",oldTextFieldValue];
}
```

And then in the Delegate function, call that action? Something like

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)UItextfield {
[self Calculate:self]
}
```

I tried that, it doesn't work. I know it'll get me to the same result but I just want to know if it can be done. I think i'm asking can a method (Calculate) be called in another method (textFieldDidEndEditing) and how.

Comment: Try `[self Calculate:UItextfield];`. You send a `self` but this I not see implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling other methods from methods happen all the time in most programming languages.
It's a great way to split code up and reuse code in different places without having to copy/paste.

(This might be too basic for you. Sorry in that case)

Things may be easier to understand if you use standard naming conventions too. ('likeThis' for variables and method names; 'LikeThis' for class names)

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     NSString *oldTextFieldValue = textField.text;
     textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %%",oldTextFieldValue];
}
```

`textField` here, is the pointer to the UITextField object which just finished editing.
You want to pass this object to your new 'other' method.

```
[self calculate:textField];
```

`self` is a pointer to an instance of the current class. For example, in a UIViewController subclass called 'MyViewController', self refers to the current instance of this class.
Since the `-calculate` method is an instance method (beginning with a '-') it requires you to use `self`. The variable `textField` is passed after the colon.

```
- (void)calculate: (UITextField*)textField {
NSString *oldTextFieldValue = textField.text;
textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %%",oldTextFieldValue];
```

}

Use only the `IBAction` keyword when you want the method to be called from a UIComponent in an xib or storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You are providing `self` as the method argument which is the instance of the class you are in. Which in this case is wrong since the method argument should be an instance of `UITextField`. Try instead `[self Calculate:UItextfield]` in your method.

Comment: OK that worked perfectly! Thanks

Is there any chance I can get a bit of an explanation just to help my understanding? Here's my assumptions, please tell me if they're OK.

'self' refers to the current object, in this case, the textfield that is being edited.

Calculate is the method and UItextfield is the paramter that needs to be passed which in tis case, is the one being edited?

Also, would it cause any problems in the future having UITextfield as the parameter for the method Calculate AND textFieldDidEndEditing method?

Thanks

Comment: self is the current instance of the class. So calling [self Calculate:textfield] means that the current instance should send a message to the method Calculate with the method argument textField. There should not be any problems. You can mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.